# Building a packet to send to a minecraft server - python

Tags: python, minecraft

I've been trying for hours (literally) to send a packet to a minecraft server.
http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_Server_Protocol#Packet_Protocol
(The player identification bit).
But I'm getting the error 'struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object'.
Here's the code:
`packet = struct.pack('bb8s110sb', 0, 7, username, verification_key, 0)  # packet type
s.send(packet)`

How can I successfully send the player identification packet to the server?

Any help is much appreciated and I will not be able to reply to any answers for at least 12 hours from when this is posted. +Rep for any help, thanks :)

Comment: The code you've shared is working correctly as packet is formed so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The struct's pack function requires that username and verification_key are byte objects.

In python 3 when you define a string like so, 'asdf', it is encoded using unicode. In order to support many encodings python has the byte object. To convert your strings into byte objects you only have to call their encode method with the desired encoding as an argument. In this case 'ascii' will work for both of your variables so,

packet = struct.pack('bb8s110sb', 0, 7, username.encode('ascii'), verification_key.encode('ascii'), 0)

should solve your problem.

Comment: hmmm, in that case one of your variables is already encoded as a byte object. The question is which one, you can check by printing them. If they are a byte object they'll look like this b'is a byte'. In which case you won't need to encode it.